# Are all finite groups extensions of other groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

I'm working on my dissertation about semidirect products. I'm ending with a proof of Schur's Theorem and using factor sets to construct the quaternion. For my final discussion I'm looking for a group that cannot be constructed using factor sets. So I believe i'm looking for a group that has no abelian normal subgroups. Ideally not a simple group as they have no normal subgroups at all so aren't a true limitation of my work.

Thanks In advance

Comment: So you basically want a group with only non-abelian normal subgroups?

Comment: Any direct product of (non-abelian) simple groups with pairwise relatively prime order will satisfy your conditions.

Comment: $S_n$, $n\geq 5$, does not have nontrivial abelian normal subgroups, though they do have normal subgroups.

Comment: Note that the title of your question is different from the body of your question. Every non-simple group can be realized as an extension of other groups, and in the finite case, as an extension of *smaller* groups. But you are really asking about the machinery of extensions of abelian groups by other (possibly non-abelian) groups. That’s a more restricted class of groups.

Comment: I suppose what i'm asking is, are factor sets sufficient to construct all groups. If not, can you give me an example of one that can't be constructed that way.

Comment: Are you only using factor sets on abelian groups, or on arbitrary groups? The conditions are much more complicated for nonabelian groups, but it is possible to do so. If your factor sets are always factor sets of abelian groups, then I already gave you an infinite family of such groups, **in addition to simple groups** which definitely cannot be constructed as extensions at all.